# Java split keeping delimeters, line breaks and carriage returns

Tags: java, regex, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel to split a file stream with regex. I need to keep the delimeters, so I using the following regex:

`(?=\r\n[0-9]{2}00)` for windows line breaks with carriage return.

However I want to support both Windows and Linux line breaks, so I thought something like this should work:

`(?=\r?\n[0-9]{2}00)` or even `(?=(\r\n|\n)[0-9]{2}00)`

But for some reason, doing any of the options above gives me some outputs with a null value, and therefore it breaks after when I need to run some substrings, etc.

I also tested other options, like:

`(?=.\n[0-9]{2}00)`
`(?=^[0-9]{2}00)` (I keep the line break on the prev group)

but with any of them I get an empty output either at the beginning or at the end.

**EDIT:** Added the camel route

```
<route id="FileRoute" trace="false">
    <from uri="file:{{file.path}}?move=.done&amp;readLock=changed&amp;readLockCheckInterval=1500&amp;charset=UTF-8"/>

    <split streaming="true" stopOnException="true" shareUnitOfWork="true" parallelProcessing="true">
        <tokenize token="(?=\R[0-9]{2}00)" regex="true" />

        <setHeader headerName="CamelSplitIndex">
            <!-- line number basically -->
            <simple>${property.CamelSplitIndex}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelSplitComplete">
            <!-- did I read the last line? -->
            <simple>${property.CamelSplitComplete}</simple>
        </setHeader>

        <log message="Line: ${property.CamelSplitIndex}: BODY: ${body}"/>

        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${property.CamelSplitIndex} == 0</simple>
                <!-- skip first line as its a header -->
            </when>
            <otherwise>

                <setProperty propertyName="StringFound">
                    <simple>${body.substring(5,24).trim()}</simple>
                </setProperty>

                <setHeader headerName="ModifiedStringFound">
                    <simple>${property.StringFound}</simple>
                </setHeader>

                <process ref="ProcessName"/>

                <transform>
                    <simple>${body.replace(${property.StringFound}, ${header.ModifiedStringFound})}</simple>
                </transform>

                <removeHeader headerName="ModifiedStringFound"/>

            </otherwise>
        </choice>

        <aggregate strategyRef="AggregationStrategy" completionTimeout="15000">
            <correlationExpression>
                <simple>${in.header.CamelFileName}</simple>
            </correlationExpression>
            <completionTimeout>
                <header>timeout</header>
            </completionTimeout>
            <to uri="log:com.blah.blah.out"/>
        </aggregate>

    </split>

</route>
```

Error:

> org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException:
>   Failed to invoke method: .substring(5,24).trim() on null due to:
>   org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed
>   to invoke method: substring(5,24) on null due to:
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   24

File example:

```
78643756435694369    4754757864254578754578545457                                                                                                                0071
05007684546545465745     1740266981415800014580631000874120180521185558     000000000247986DFGBDFH FDGDGJHUHJK   SDFGSGDFGf      GT 541100898  00710047503051 0220180522
0501            000000  000000000000                                     046    00000103971056242218759000000000000 000000000000 000000                    00000000000  
0502            GH    001000000000000000000                                                                                                                             
05005212455451257521     1740266981415800001820031000874120180521183349     000000001817986FGHDFHFGJFGDHGDFDFH        FDGFDHGFDHDFH 541100898  00710043090051 0220180522
0501            000000  000000000000                                     046    00000100293449142130526000000000000 000000000000 000000                    00000000000  
0502            FD    001000000000000000000                                                                                                                             
05009789265762578888     1740266981415800012612361003716920180521173412     000000004859986DFHDGJFGJFGJKHGJGHJ   GDHFGHFGHFGH 541100898  00710029706451 0220180522
0501            000000  000000000000                                     046    00000103058175142271046000000000000 000000000000 000000                    00000000000  
0502            AR    001000000000000000000                                                                                                                             
05008758407825904958     1740266981415800004933011003716920180521173559     000000000798986FGHGFGHRTUJHGJDGHYHTJK    DHDGJFHJHFHJ    NJ 541100898  00710030461251 0220180522
0501            000000  000000000000                                     046    00000100902124678647109000000000000 000000000000 000000                    00000000000  
0502            TY    001000000000000000000                                                                                                                             
05004987785686893465     1740266981415800003253131003716920180521174415     000000001142986FDGFDGHFGJTYUJDFHGDEHGTGFH     DFHDYRT     BG 541100898  00710032033851 0220180522
0501            000000  000000000000                                     046    00000100620274678526079000000000000 000000000000 000000                    00000000000  
0502            UI    001000000000000000000
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Use `"\\R"` (`\R`) to match any line break sequence.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew same problem `Failed to invoke method: substring(5,24) on null due to: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 24`

Comment: Then there is some issue with the code.

Comment: @FedeE. The StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is unrelated to this regex. Could you provide additional code (including possible input and expected output) where this regex and substring is used to better understand the full picture of the issue you're having?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing this problem. A regex will not throw an SIOOBE

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew printing each output I'm noticing that the ones that are empty are all the odd ones. Really weird.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen going to edit the question to add details of the process that is executed on each output.

Comment: @AxelH done, added the camel route.

Comment: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Can you show us an example of desired input.

Comment: I've added the `[tag:apache-camel]`. Never seen it before or worked with Apache Camel myself, so can't really help you I'm afraid. Could you perhaps also add about three lines of the file you're trying to read? And are you sure all lines are at least 24 characters long?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yes, lines are all over 100 chars long. I'm gonna post an example of the file contents.

Comment: @Gatusko there, I posted an example of the file contents.

Comment: Would simply disregarding `\r` in the lookahead `(?=\n[0-9]{2}00)` work? (A superfluous \r at the end.)

Comment: @JoopEggen OMG could I be so stupid? LOL! Of course that works!